# Error With Big Decimal in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I keep getting the

> The method add(BigDecimal) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (pay)"

error with the code below.

For reference I have saved the `pay` class in a separate file, where I import `BigDecimal` as well.

Would one of you like to point out where I'm lacking/misunderstanding? I've tried to find a solution, but I couldn't find something.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class SalesPreInt { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pay pay = new Pay();
        pay.basePay();

        BigDecimal intCalc = new BigDecimal("0.15");

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What were your total sales?");
        BigDecimal salesPre = userInput.nextBigDecimal();
        System.out.println("You're Total Sales were "+salesPre);

        userInput.close();

        BigDecimal postIntCalc = salesPre.multiply(intCalc);
        BigDecimal salesCom = postIntCalc.add(salesPre);
        int finalCalc = salesCom.add(pay);

        System.out.println("Your total sales including commission is "+salesCom);
        System.out.println("Your total pay is"+finalCalc);
    }   
}
```

pay.java file below:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Pay {
    public void basePay() {
        int basePay = 50000;
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(basePay));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Pay extending BigDecimal? If not it will not work

Comment: `pay pay = new pay();` is an accident waiting to happen - consider using the Java naming convention, ie capitalize class names. That would make it `Pay pay = new Pay();`

Comment: Does that mean I have to declare "pay" as big decimal as well? I thought I had done so in the pay class file, or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Does `pay.basePay()` return a `BigDecimal`?  I believe you'd want to use that instead of having `Pay` extend it.

Comment: It might be better to post the code for the pay class as well, it's really hard to follow what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: in the pay.java file I have basePay as a bigdecimal, so I thought if I were to call that method from that class it would be the same? I am guessing not :/

Comment: pay class file

      

'  import java.math.BigDecimal;

        public class Pay
        {
 public void Pay(){
 
 int basePay = 50000;
 java.math.BigDecimal bd = new java.math.BigDecimal(String.valueOf(basePay));
 }
        }'

Comment: ^I might be too new here but I tried to enter the code correctly(and tried to edit it once i saw that jumbled up mess), but alas it seems the dubm has gotten me today :/

Comment: @DougCoats If you like to add code, then please update your question. If you renamed `pay` to `Pay`, then please update the `SalesPreInt` code as well. Btw: your comment misses the `basePay` method. (To the other comment: you can't format your code in a comment. That is why you should add it to the question ;)).

Comment: Thanks! I learned something :D

So If i am understanding you correctly, basically in the pay.java file there actually isnt a method, which is where my issue is?

Comment: Are you sure? With this Pay class SalesPreInit should give totally different error messages - eg on this line `pay.basePay();`

Comment: Just to be sure: the code in the question: is this the same code you have for `SalesPreInt` and `Pay`? No differences? Is the error message still the one in the question?

Comment: youre right now im getting this :/

pay cannot be resolved to a type
 The method basePay() is undefined for the type Pay
 The method add(BigDecimal) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (Pay)

Comment: Sorry guys didnt realize I copy and pasted somethign i tried earlier instea dof the correct code

So @Tom, yes the orignal error message still applies

The method add(BigDecimal) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (Pay)

Comment: I don't want to guess: am I correct if I assume that with `int finalCalc = salesCom.add(pay);` you want the basepay, that has to be produced by the Pay class, to be added to salesCom to produced finalCalc?

Comment: @fvu correct.  It looks like maybe instead of int i should have declared a bigdecimal?

Comment: Since you're new, please read these to pages: [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Since you don' have not enough reputation to vote yet, you only can accept an answer. It is up to you if you like to accept an answer and which one you like to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message tells you, the `add` method of `BigDecimal` with one argument expects a `BigDecimal` instance: [[javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add-java.math.BigDecimal-)]

> *public BigDecimal add(BigDecimal augend)*
>
> Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this + augend), and whose scale
>   is max(this.scale(), augend.scale()).
>
> **Parameters:**
>       *augend* - value to be added to this BigDecimal.
>
> **Returns:**
>       *this + augend*

You've passed a variable of type `Pay` to this method and since `Pay` is not a subtype of `BigDecimal` it is not related to it. The method `add` can't know how to add a `Pay` instance, the compiler complains about that argument type.

You can do the following fix, to bypass that problem:

Your `basePay` method creates a `BigDecimal` and I guess this is the one you like to add to `salesCom`, so change that method a bit:

```
public BigDecimal basePay() {
    int basePay = 50000;
    return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(basePay));
}
```

This method now creates a `BigDecimal` and returns it to the calling method. Now change the `add` method call to use the `basePay` method:

```
int finalCalc = salesCom.add(pay.basePay());
```

Now there is only one problem left. As you can see in the JavaDoc posted above, `add` returns a new `BigDecimal` instance, but you're assigning the returned value to the variable `finalCalc`, which is of type `int`. So we need to change it to `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal finalCalc = salesCom.add(pay.basePay());
```

Now your code compiles and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Pay class to return a basePay value, you need a proper method for that, ie a method that actually returns the value, ie not a void method.

```
public class Pay {
    private int basePay = 50000;

    public BigDecimal getBasepay() {
        // no need to pass via strings, BigDecimal has a constructor that takes an int value
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(basePay);
        return bd;
    }
}
```

which will be called like

```
int finalCalc = salesCom.add(pay.getBasepay()).intValue();
```

as you want to store the result as an integer, or

```
BigDecimal finalCalc = salesCom.add(pay.getBasepay());
```

Notice that I declared basePay - the value - as a private member of the Pay class, and renamed the method to start with get (called a getter in Java, and by convention their names are prefixed with get). If some day you need a way to modify that value, just add a setter

```
public void setBasepay(int bp) {
    basePay = bp;
}
```

And maybe you also want to be able to set the value directly as a BigDecimal although it's stored as an int? Just add

```
public void setBasepay(BigDecimal bp) {
    basePay = bp.intValue();
}
```

Two methods with the same name but other arguments is called overloading, and that's an often-used mechanism to introduce flexibility and versatility in your programs.

I would also suggest you have a look at a good tutorial, the [official one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) is pretty good (and free :))